# Adding url parameters in Wordpress search

Tags: wordpress, url, search

Am customizing a search form in WordPress and I can't seem to be able to add other parameters to the form. Below is my form

```
<form id="searchform" action="/">
            <div class="row">
                    <input type="input" name="searchvalue" class="searchinput" placeholder="Search..">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <label>Province</label>
                    <select name="province" id="province" class="filterpostsbyprovince">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Province</option>

</select>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" style="cursor: pointer">

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="filtersearch" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="s" value="search">               
    </form>
```

Based on the above form my search query should be something like `?s=search&filtersearch=1&province=""&searchvalue=""` however WordPress passes on s=search to the search results page. I've added filtersearch on my functions file but this doesn't seem to help

```
 function filter_add_query_vars($query_vars) {   
      $query_vars[] = 'filtersearch'; 
      return $query_vars;
    }
   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'filter_add_query_vars' );
```

I have tried removing permalinks but this doesn't help. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer, but you might want to look into using $_GET variables given how you're structuring this.

You'd want your permalink to look like this (notice the quotes are removed):

```
?s=search&filtersearch=1&province=Example&searchvalue=Another-Example
```

To get the value of province, you'd use this in your PHP:

```
$province = $_GET['province']
```

You should then be able to use that in a function to filter your search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am creating a form so I can't use a permalink, am getting the province value from a dropdown on the form. The issue is that Wordpress automatically strips out variable it doesn't recognise before building the page therefore 
    ` ?s=search&filtersearch=1&province=Example&searchvalue=Another-Example`
ends up as 
     `?s=search`

Your supposed to add the new variable either in a plugin or in the function file (see filter_add_query_vars above) but that wasn't working for me. I ended up having to add the variables directly onto the wordpress query string